# There is a Lag in text box typing in Angularjs Application

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat, lag

We have a Chat application. To show chat history we are using ng-repeat. when number of records in history is more than 100 then there is lag in typing in new message text box. When I type something in text box it takes around 0.5 to 1 seconds to display that character in text box. This lag is not coming when number of records in ng-repeat less.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ng-repeat` for chat history, because Angular maintains observers to every line in `ng-repeat`. You might also try one-time bindings in `ng-repeat` and `track by`, but I would recommend old-style DOM manipulation in history widget. Because history is usually immutable append-only thing, there is no point to put it under control of Angularjs.

Comment: Thanks for reply..  old-style DOM manipulation means append html using innerHTML()  or append() html ? What are the other ways of  DOM manipulation ?

Comment: Yes, they are. If you not using jQuery then consider `element.appendChild(..)` and  `element.innerHTML`

Comment: thanks .. Found one similar post      https://www.codeproject.com/tips/1101082/angularjs-ng-repeat-alternative-approach

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously an ng-repeat performance problem. You can get over it by using "track by".

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"></div>
```